# Snapshot and create new EC2 Spot Instance on AWS termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

For a while, we have been looking into Spot Instances and have a question about them.

Is it possible (and if yes, how), to run a Spot Instance and attach an Elastic IP to it, and if AWS terminates the spot instance, to make a snapshot of the terminal instances, deploy it to a new spot instance, delete the snapshot and move over the Elastic IP.

Is this possible? And if it is, how would we be able to make it as stated above?

Comment: If AWS terminates the spot instance, there's a reason for that, and you most likely won't be able to launch another one like it for a while, because spot instances are generally terminated only when no capacity is available of that type for that price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally using spot you shouldn't be keeping data on the instance. Keep it on EFS or S3 and use the spot instance as compute only.

Having said that, you can choose to have your instance [stopped, terminated, or hibernated](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/spot-interruptions.html) if you lose your spot instance. I suggest you look into using the "stop" option.

I'm not sure there's any built in function to allocate an EIP to a new spot instance. You could probably look at doing something with the userdata script which runs on startup. And of course you can do almost anything with lambda.

Your best approach could be to an an AMI of your system available, which you can spin up any way you like. You could look at [EC2 fleet](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/scale-instances-across-purchase-options-in-a-single-ASG/) which can let your autoscaling group use spot and on-demand instances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was actually looking into setting up a simple HTTP proxy, so there isn't any data. Just the compute, the elastic IP would be so that I can set it up on that IP, hence why I was thinking of that.

Comment: Great, then my answer applies then. You simply have an AMI set up that does the job. Could an ELB / ALB do the same job? Generally having a proxy that can disappear at any time isn't good for system reliability.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work. I am looking for a HTTP proxy that I can forward traffic to from a VM I run at home.